# Vertex seem to mantain weight no matter what I do

Tags: vertices, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

Hi so I'm having rpoblems with this Mesh:
[image]

This set of vertex, no matter what I do, don't seem to loose their 100% weight. I tried to delete the vertex group and paint again but the result is the same. I deactivated auto-nomtalize and still they continue to move in the same way. I unweighted the bone and the same happens

-oddly enough when I did the opposite (re-assign the vertex to a new group) the part below the line doesn't deform according to the weight

I think it has something to do with the fact that I stitched that part of the neck to the other part of the neck that has the head of the model. I did it All by joining vertices.

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you say that you've tried to delete the vertex group but if these vertices are part of another group they will still be part of this other group and the corresponding bone will continue to move this vertices, so maybe first select these vertices, go into the dropdown menu on the right of the vertex groups list and choose Remove from All Groups

Comment: It's probably because those vertices aren't weighted to any other bones.  Weights are *relative* weights of multiple bones.  It doesn't matter what number (or color) your weight is if the vertex isn't weighted to any other bone.